# Get email on OAuth Twitter (Php)

Tags: php, email, twitter, oauth

I use Php for **twitter autorization** (OAuth). Can not get **user email** in response.

```
define('ACCOUNT_EMAIL','https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json');
$oauth_nonce = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$oauth_timestamp = time();

$oauth_token = $response['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret = $response['oauth_token_secret'];
$screen_name = $response['screen_name'];

//create oauth signature
$params = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key=' . CONSUMER_KEY . URL_SEPARATOR,
    'oauth_nonce=' . $oauth_nonce . URL_SEPARATOR,
    'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1' . URL_SEPARATOR,
    'oauth_timestamp=' . $oauth_timestamp . URL_SEPARATOR,
    'oauth_token=' . $oauth_token . URL_SEPARATOR,
    'oauth_version=1.0' . URL_SEPARATOR,
    'screen_name=' . $screen_name,
    //'include_email=true'
);
$oauth_base_text = 'GET' . URL_SEPARATOR . urlencode(ACCOUNT_EMAIL) . URL_SEPARATOR . implode('', array_map('urlencode', $params));

$key = CONSUMER_SECRET . '&' . $oauth_token_secret;
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $oauth_base_text, $key, true));

// get userinfo
$params = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key=' . CONSUMER_KEY,
    'oauth_nonce=' . $oauth_nonce,
    'oauth_signature=' . urlencode($signature),
    'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp=' . $oauth_timestamp,
    'oauth_token=' . urlencode($oauth_token),
    'oauth_version=1.0',
    'screen_name=' . $screen_name,
    //'include_email=true'
);

$url = ACCOUNT_EMAIL . '?' . implode(URL_SEPARATOR, $params);
$response = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($response);
```

**When **include_email=true** is open - **i get nothing.**
When **include_email=true** is block - i get all userinfo (without email).**

In my admin profile I set **Request email addresses from users** and send info for special permission in twitter support.
Regenerate keys too.
What is problem in it&

Comment: file_get_contents will discard the response body (were you will likely find a human-readable error message), in case the HTTP status code indicates an error. Go research how to avoid that (involves passing in a stream context), or use something else to make the request (such a cURL), that doesn’t automatically keep the response body from you in case of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add cURL

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($result);
```

**1 way**

```
url =  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXX&oauth_nonce=XXXXXX&oauth_signature=XXXXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1509963372&oauth_token=XXXXXX&oauth_version=1.0&screen_name=ssds
```

**result** = HTTP/1.1 200 OK + all field without email

**2 way**

```
url =  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXX&oauth_nonce=XXXXXX&oauth_signature=XXXXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1509963372&oauth_token=XXXXXX&oauth_version=1.0&screen_name=ssds&include_email=true
```

**result** = HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required +  {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

2 way with email not work.

Comment: Has anyone been able to get the email from this api call?  I having the same issue as mention above

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and get email!

*This is view of last url*

```
define('ACCOUNT_EMAIL','https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, ACCOUNT_EMAIL . '?include_email=true&screen_name='.$screen_name);
```